# How to call method of another class from differnet class in Xamarin

Tags: forms, image, xamarin, xamarin.android, popover

I am new to xamarin.forms.

On main page I have button "Select Photos". When user click popup open with number of images. When user tap and image popup closes.

I want to do is when popup close; I want to display the selected image on main page so user know what image they selected.

So I have method on the popup page for image click. In the method I save the image name as variable. And I try to call another method which is on main page. The Method on the main page would get the variable and display the Image.

This is code when user tap image

```
        public void Idpty1(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            Signtype = "1";

            //save the image name as variable
            SelectedTypeImage = "idpty1.png";

            //On the Newphoto page; call close popup function. 
            new NewPhotoPage().ClosePopover();
}
```

This is function on main page and I am trying to call this function with above function.

```
 public void ClosePopover()
     {

       //Close the popover 
       PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();

       //Get the variable which was set on the popover page (image name)
       SelectedTypeImage = MyPopupPage.SelectedTypeImage;

        // Source the image from variable. 
        SelectedType.Source = SelectedTypeImage ;


        //DisplayAlert("Alert2", SelectedTypeImage, "ok");

         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("test");
    }
```

This is image code in the main page

```
<Image x:Name="SelectedType" Resources=""></Image>
```

In the above code; image part does not work, image source does not work also display alert does not work. BUT SYSTEM.DEBUG WORKS.

What I don't understand is function does get call but even display alert does not work.

Comment: In your code DisplayAlert is in a comment. Also, have you checked the value in SelectedTypeImage?

Comment: I checked the value is coming through fine and I have uncommented the display alert. But still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use something like

```
public void Idpty1(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            Signtype = "1";

            //save the image name as variable
            SelectedTypeImage = "idpty1.png";

            //On the Newphoto page; call close popup function. 
           // new NewPhotoPage().ClosePopover();
Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Send<App> ((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "CallMethod");
}
```

in the constructor of Main Page.

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe(this, "CallMethod", (sender) => {
// do something
ClosePopover();  // <-- run u' method.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On your `Newphoto` page, just call `ClosePopover` method as:

```
YOURCLASSNAME.ClosePopover();
```

assuming they are in the same namespace. 
Else, use `using` to add the namespace of your class.
Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: This is what I am doing. If you look in the first batch of code in my original question. It has line          " new NewPhotoPage().ClosePopover();" I am caling method. Method does get called fine. But If I have the displayAlert in method; it does not work.

Comment: You can try these two things:  1. Use `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` to invoke the DisplayAlert method on the main thread 2. `await DisplayAlert("", "", "");`

Comment: Thank you for your help @Oluwasayo Babalola. The above solution has sorted the issue out.

Comment: Awesome. Glad I could help

Comment: @@Oluwasayo Babalola. This is an different Issue I was facing other day. Unfortunately still not resolved. Do you know much about Exif stuff. I have developed an app that takes photo. I have field below photo for Notes. I want to save notes to photo comments. Is this possible in xamarin. Thanks you in advance.

Comment: This is link to my exif question. It explain more on this link.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52409118/how-to-use-exifinterface-in-xamarin-android?noredirect=1#comment91822288_52409118

Comment: I don't really know much about Exif right now. I can take a look at it and answer your question(that's not a promise :) )

Comment: Thank you for you help in advance